# EXCEPTION: No provider for HeroService?

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched for this question but didn't found, and tried a lot to solve this problem but I am new in angular 2 and creating demo app with help of angular docs.
My app was running successfully before some time. But when I add new service then I got this exception:

**EXCEPTION: No provider for HeroService!**

I am sure I am doing wrong somewhere, can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?

**Folder structure:**

```
app
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
    hero.service.ts
    hero.ts
    hero-detail.component.ts
    main.ts
    mock-hero.ts
node_modules ...
index.html
package.json
styles.css
systemjs.config.js
tsconfig.json
```

**app.component.ts-**

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
       <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
              [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
              (click)="onSelect(hero)">
           <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
       </li>
    </ul>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`,
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

**hero.service.ts-**

```
// hero.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  };
getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
    setTimeout(() => resolve(this.getHeroes()), 2000);
  });
}
}
```

**hero.ts-**

```
//hero.ts
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**mock-heroes.ts-**

```
//mock-heroes.ts
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
  {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
];
```

**app.module.ts-**

```
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { MyComponent }  from './my.component';
import { ShubhComponent }  from './my.component';

import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ,MyComponent,HeroDetailComponent,ShubhComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

for better understanding I am attaching snapshot:

[image]

Comment: You have to use providers instead of injectables

Comment: can you share app.module.ts ?

Comment: Thanks, But can you please be specific. I am using @Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  };

Comment: I have attached app.module.ts.

Comment: you to declare your service in a provider array either in the app.module.ts(if you want the service as singleton for whole app) or in the component(if you want service for only the component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      providers: [Your Service Name],
      template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
           <h2>My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
                  [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
                  (click)="onSelect(hero)">
               <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
           </li>
        </ul>
        <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks MMK,  it worked for me. I forgot to add     "providers: [HeroService]"  in app.component.ts file. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great @ShubhamVerma

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the service in the module that loads the component that uses it.
In your case, load it in app.module, at providers array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your service in the providers section of the @NgModule :

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroService } from './service/hero.service.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers : [HeroService],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the doc of NgModule : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: It is not working, i attached import { HeroService } from './hero.service.ts';
  declarations: [ AppComponent ,MyComponent,HeroDetailComponent,ShubhComponent,HeroService],
 in app.module.ts. but still it is not working.
but then i added  "providers: [HeroService]" in app.component.ts file then its working. - Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare your service in a provider array either in the

1. app.module.ts(if you want the service as singleton for whole app)

> ```
>   @NgModule({
>   imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
>   declarations: [ AppComponent ,MyComponent,HeroDetailComponent,ShubhComponent],
>   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
>   providers: [HeroService]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

or

2. in the component(if you want service for only the component).

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template:`<h1>{{title}}</h1>
          <h2>My Heroes</h2>
       <ul class="heroes">
           <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
                 [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
                 (click)="onSelect(hero)">
              <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
          </li>
       </ul>
       <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>`,
      providers: [HeroService]
   })

Comment: Thanks Suraj ,but its not working after adding providers: [HeroService] in app.module.ts. But after adding in app.components.ts then its working. - Thank You so Much

Comment: as@MMK's answer

Answer (score 0):

Add  `providers: [Service Name]` in your component.

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      providers: [Service Name],
     ...............
    ................

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the service as a Provider at the app.module

[image]